# ID3 Android MediaScanner

Tags: android, media-player, audio-player, android-music-player

Android extracts the ID3 tags and displays in the native Music player app.
I wish to know if it is possible to access the ID3 tags that have already been extracted by Android.

I am writing a media-player application and wish to use MediaScanner to scan the media and use the ID3/artists/etc extracted by Android

Answer (score 1):

Android adds all of the information extracted and inserted into the media provider's database. You can access this information using the columns defined in the [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) class.

Unfortunately there's no direct way to access any other ID3 information available in the tags.