# Get Song Information with Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am writing a program which I would like to have give the user the information of their songs. How would I have the program go into the phone's root directory and get the information of the songs? I know where the songs are located on the devices. I am targeting OS 2.2 if the makes a difference.

Comment: I assume you're talking about MP3s - right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ID3 Android MediaScanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682376/id3-android-mediascanner)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an ID3 tag reader. You could try and start here: http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/.